# Multiple Selection for UITableView does not work

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, ios5, multi-select

I am trying to implement multiple selection for my tableView. In Interface Builder I found the 2 options **Selection** and **Editing** which I set accordingly to **Multiple Selection** and **Multiple Selection During Editing**. If I simulate the XIB in the simulator it let's me select several rows. As soon as I simulate my code though, I only have single selection active. 
I tried enabling it programmatically via

```
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:YES];
[self.tableView setAllowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing:YES];
```

in the viewDidLoad. Interestingly this resulted in the error **'-[UITableView setAllowsMultipleSelection:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9939e00'**.

PS: My tableView is a grouped tableView, I am mentioning this, as all the examples I saw so far were plain tableViews only.
I am using XCode 4.2.1 and set the target iOS for my project to iOS 5.0

Comment: Did you check if your tableView IBOutlet object properly connected to the Interface builder object (if your tableView is not created programatically)?

Comment: Yes the tableView is working fine, only the multiple selection is not working. The tableView is loaded, I can select a single row and process it, though deselect also did not work, I just realized, even though I have coded the deselect method in order to remove the deselected object from my array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {

        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        //add object in an array
    }
    else{

        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        //remove the object at the index from array


    }
}
```

Comment: So that worked for the multiple selection, thanks. However, as many other developers I was struggling with the 'reusable-cell' issue, meaning, that the checkmarks disappeared when scrolling and appeared randomly on others. I solved that with an additional array, keeping track of the row which has been checked. Thanks for the input Simone.

Comment: With the array now works properly? I have the same issue